# Generating Function Approach giving wrong combination count while normal brute force casework approach giving correct answer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am solving a problem: How many words are less than four letters long and contain only the letters A, B, C, D, and E? Here, 'word' refers to any string of letters.

**My Solution 1 uses Generating functions** gives wrong answer

$(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3)$

where $(1+x+x^2+x^3)$ is Generating function for each letter. This approach gave a wrong answer $(35+15+5+1)$ which is the sum of coefficients of $(x^3, x^2, x, 1)$ in $$x^{15} + 5 x^{14} + 15 x^{13} + 35 x^{12} + 65 x^{11} + 101 x^{10} + 135 x^9 + 155 x^8 + 155 x^7 + 135 x^6$$ $$+ 101 x^5 + 65 x^4 + 35 x^3 + 15 x^2 + 5 x + 1$$

**Correct Approach using Case Work** gives the correct answer

Case 1: The word is one letter long. Clearly, there are $5$ of these words.

Case 2: The word is two letters long. Constructing the set of these words, there are $5$ options for the first letter and $5$ options for the second letter, so there are $5^2 = 25$ of these words.

Case 3: The word is three letters long. By similar logic as above, we have $5$ options for the first letter, $5$ options for the second, and $5$ options for the third. Then there are $5^3 = 125$ of these letters.

Adding all our cases up, there are $5 + 25 + 125 = 155$ words that are less than four letters long and contain only the letters A, B, C, D, and E.

**Could Someone help me in explaining why the Generating function approach failed here?**

Comment: Typesetting tip:  To obtain $x^{15}$, type `$x^{15}$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to consider whether the e.g.f. (exponential generating function) approach is worth while here for such a short problem. However, the approach would stand you in good stead for more complex problems.

You will have to extract from the [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E3%2F6%29%5E5+) of $(1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!)^5$,

(coefficient of $x$) + $2!$(coefficient of $x^2$) + $3!$(coefficient of $x^3$)

The factorials in the denominator of the exponential generating function effectively compensate the permutations for a letter occurring multiple times

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the key is Exponential Generating Functions that give the permutations while the normal generating functions give the combinations. I can see that 0!*0 + 1! * 5 + 2! * 25/2 + 3! * 125 / 6 = 155

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;$(-:

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary Generating functions does not calculate the permutations. It gives the combinations and thus order is not taken into account. So, second appraoch gives right answer.

Comment: Consider exponential generating functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).